# Lottie Animation works only once on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, lottie

I am using Lottie Animation and want it to animate everytime I click on it , To this I am using `GestureDetector` However it only works the first time then for some reason it wont work again

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() {
    return _AppState();
  }
}

class _AppState extends State<App> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController my_location_controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    my_location_controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        body: Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                my_location_controller.forward();
              },
              child: Lottie.asset(
                'assets/my_location.json',
                controller: my_location_controller,
                animate: true,
                repeat: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a listener to reset your animation when it gets completed, like this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    my_location_controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 5));
    my_location_controller.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        my_location_controller.reset();
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ante Bule thnx, will accept your answer and this seems to work too ..

```
 child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                my_location_controller.reset();
                my_location_controller.forward();
              },
              child: Lottie.asset(
                'assets/my_location.json',
                controller: my_location_controller,
               
              ),
```

Comment: Yes, that's one of the ways too.